# ionic 3 calendar plugin

Tags: angular, calendar, ionic3

I found this [site](https://thielcole.github.io/ionic2/2017/02/03/Ionic2-Calendar.html)in which it helps you implement a calendar in ionic. I followed each step but this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzkWr.png)  popped up to me. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to import from `@angular/animation`?

Following the [github document](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar). You probably want to import it from

`import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`

Comment: I actually did that already, but it didn't solve the problem. But thanks anyway, I found an alternative calendar plugin which worked for me.

Comment: What was the alternative?